# Max and min bounds on number of DB results without affecting performance

Tags: sql, h2

I want to select rows from a database with bounds on the number of results. I always want to have a minimum number of results returned, even if that means ignoring my other criteria, and I never want to have more than a maximum amount.

My current query looks like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM Athletes WHERE Height > 72
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Athletes
    ORDER BY Height DESC
    FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The idea here is that I want to find all athletes taller than six feet (72"). If there are more than ten, I just want any ten of them, but if there are fewer than three, I want the three tallest athletes even if some are under six feet.

This works fine on my test data, but I'd like to get rid of the `UNION` for production. How can I rewrite this without any performance-draining bits like `UNION` or `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a CTE:

```
with ten as (
      SELECT *
      FROM Athletes
      WHERE Height > 72
      FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
     )
select t.*
from ten
where (select count(*) from ten) >= 3
union all
select a.*
from atheletes
where (select count(*) from ten) < 3
order by height desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

I think this should be pretty fast, because counting 10 rows in a table should be quite fast and there is no duplicate elimination.

EDIT:

Another method uses window functions but is likely to be less performant:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             sum(case when height > 72 then 1 else 0 end) over () as num_gt72,
             row_number() over (order by height desc) as seqnum
      from (select a.*
            from athletes a
            order by height desc
            fetch first 10 rows only
           ) a
     ) a
where seqnum <= num_gt72 or
      (seqnum <= 3 and num_gt72 < 3);
```